# Set permanent data in an Azure Data Explorer table

Tags: datatable, azure-data-explorer

I must be missing something basic, as this functionality seems so simple. 
I created a table in the Azure Data Explorer cluster I am working in,

```
.create table MyCows (CowName:string, CowType:string);
```

Now I want to enter data into that table that will always be there, even after my querying work is done, that data should persist in the table. I don't want to ingest it from somewhere else, I don't want to have to run a query to set the values each time I enter this cluster, I just want the data to persist in this table perpetually.

I just want to input 4 records to the table.
"Bill", "Vanilla"
"Bela", "Rum"
"Clark", "Smooth"
"Randy", "Chocolate"

How can I do this? 
I tried variations on 'let' such as

```
let MyCows = ["Bill", "Vanilla"]
```

and other variations without luck. The ingest command does not seem to be what I want either as that has to point to a file, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

the following are perhaps the 2 simplest of options:

1. using `.ingest inline`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-ingestion/ingest-inline

   - e.g.:

   ```
   .ingest inline into table T <|
   Bill,Vanilla
   Bela,Rum
   Clark,Smooth
   Randy,Chocolate
   ```
2. using `.set-or-append`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-ingestion/ingest-from-query

   - e.g.:

   ```
   .set-or-append T <| 
      datatable(CowName:string, CowType:string)
      [
         "Bill", "Vanilla",
         "Bela", "Rum",
         "Clark", "Smooth",
         "Randy", "Chocolate
      ]
   ```

make sure you configure the table's [retention policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/retentionpolicy) to comply with your requirements of never dropping the data (e.g. put something like `36500.00:00:00` - 36500 days - as the `SoftDeletePeriod`)